# Threading with parameters fails

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have following code:

```
Thread userThread = new Thread(() => UserPasswordSpawn.InputBox(ref userName, ref password));
//UserPassWordSpawn.InputBox(ref userName, ref password);
/* do some calculations while user puts in data */

userThread.Join();
```

The thread does not work, and never enters the InputBox() function (I set a breakpoint there, and it is never reached), while it works just fine if I do the commented part (but the calculations which should happen while the system is waiting for the user to input the data). How can I spawn a thread with 2 input parameters properly (twice ref string).

Note, the error I get is something about Thread.JoinInternal(), but the main thing is probably that the function is not called.

The call with the () => ThreadStart() I got from [How to pass parameters to ThreadStart method in Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread)

Comment: `userThread.Start();` :)

Comment: you are not starting the thread.why not use tpl.threads created like this are costly

Comment: I do not see a userThread.start(). Can you include that part of your code as well ?

Comment: you didn't start the thread... you only created it

Comment: Doh, okay, that was just dumb. Yeah, that was it -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this:

```
Thread userThread = new Thread(() => UserPasswordSpawn.InputBox(ref userName, ref password));
```

you've created new `thread` instance.
Now you should start it by in a way like that:

```
userThread.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the reason. Somehow I am used to C++, where that is not needed explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Call `userThread.Start();` after creating the thread, and before joining it.