# Passing a method to another method for thread starting

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently in the process of creating a class that has general methods that specialised methods of the class call. One of these general methods needs to get a method as parameter to use it to start a new thread.

My question is how this parameter must be done (thus what I must replace  with, or what do I need to change in total to make it work as intended):

```
Class mytest
{
   public void myPublicStarter()
   {
       Starter("Test", this.DoWork);
   }

   public void DoWork(object myIDString)
   {

   }

   private void Starter(string myIDString, <METHOD> paramethod)
   {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(paramethod);
        myThread.Start(myIDString);
   }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to ThreadStart method in Thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's not a dup. he's looking for the parameter type.

Comment: have a look: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I don't think that this is a duplicate.  It's not asking how to pass parameters to a thread entry method but rather how to pass the thread entry method itself.

Comment: Exactly. I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread before I posted this thread but it didnt answer how to pass the method itself to another method to THERE then start the thread. That is why I made this question.

Comment: @ThomasE. Stone comment have the answer.

Comment: not completely. As there is Func used in that one questions answers there. And Func needs a return parameter (which I don't have).
The answers here with Action or ParameterizedThreadStart work with no return value (Func on the other hand needs one).

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new `Thread` object you have to pass it a delegate, i.e. an object that refers to a method.  That delegate must be type `ThreadStart` if the entry method has no parameters and `ParameterizedThreadStart` if it does.  In your case, your `DoWork` method has a parameter so the delegate type must be the latter.  Because the `paramethod` parameter is declared as that type, the compiler knows to cast `this.DoWork` as that type when you call `Starter`.  If the method signature did not match that of the delegate then a compilation error would occur.

```
public void myPublicStarter()
{
    Starter("Test", this.DoWork);
}

public void DoWork(object myIDString)
{

}

private void Starter(string myIDString, ParameterizedThreadStart paramethod)
{
     Thread myThread = new Thread(paramethod);
     myThread.Start(myIDString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in .NET you have the concept of delegates, and you have Actions and Functions which are in fact just delegates.

A Function represents a function that takes some input parameters and has a return value.
An action represents a method that takes some input parameters but doesn't return any value.

So it's depending on what you woud like to achieve.

Here's a demo sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myPublicStarter();
}

public static void myPublicStarter()
{
    Starter("Test", () => DoWork("My Id String Passed here"));
}

public static void DoWork(object myIDString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myIDString);
}

private static void Starter(string myIDString, Action paramethod)
{
    paramethod.Invoke();
}
```

}

Note: I've made the classes static as I've converted it to a console application.

[image: That's the output.]

Now, to adapt the code to work with threads, you can use the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myPublicStarter();
}

public static void myPublicStarter()
{
    Starter("Test", x => DoWork("My Id String Passed here"));
}

public static void DoWork(object myIDString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myIDString);
}

private static void Starter(string myIDString, Action<object> paramethod)
{
    Thread myThread = new Thread(x => paramethod(x));
    myThread.Start(myIDString);
}
```

This will generate the exact same output as listed above.