# New Thread does not see the supplied method from the same namespace

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am trying to figure out what am I doing wrong in the following script. I am getting an error ***"Method Name Expected"*** when starting a new Thread for the **"del"** delegate. The method **getUrlThread** is clearly defined and the delegate **del** is pointing to it so why is it not being seen? Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace updateNewFrontEnd
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // define function pointer
        // =======================
        public delegate string getUrlThreadDelegate(string targetUrl);

        // define function for the function pointer
        // ========================================
        public string getUrlThread(string targetUrl)
        {

            httpRequestClass urlResponseText = new httpRequestClass();

            urlResponseText.TargetUrl = targetUrl;

            string text = urlResponseText.getUrlResponse();

            return text;
        }


        private void btnUrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // top decalrations
            // ================

            .... some code here....

            string targetUrl = "some string here...";


            // instantiate the HTTP call object to the "targetUrl" url
            // =======================================================

            getUrlThreadDelegate del = new getUrlThreadDelegate(getUrlThread);


            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(del(targetUrl))); // ERROR HERE !!!
            t1.Start();


            .... some more code here....

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but currently you're *calling* `del` here:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(del(targetUrl)))
```

You've got a fundamental problem though - the method you're trying to call doesn't have the right signature for `ThreadStart` (which is a `void` parameterless delegate). It's not clear what you want to do with the response returned by `getUrlThread`, but you could use a lambda expression to *call* the method more simply without declaring your own delegate type:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => getUrlThread(targetUrl));
t1.Start();
```

That will fetch the value - but then throw it away.

As an aside - but an important one - it would *really* help the readability of your code if you'd follow .NET naming conventions. Namespace, type and method names should be `PascalCased`, not `camelCased`.

Additionally, you might want to consider using `async`/`await`... or at least use `Task<T>` if you're using .NET 4.0 or higher.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. What I was trying to achieve the following: On the "btnUrl_Click" event a new delegate (named "del") for the "getUrlThread" method is created. That method reference is called by a new Thread "t" and should run its course (whatever happens on that thread does not matter for now). You say..."parameter-less delegate..." but it is clearly defined as: "public delegate string getUrlThreadDelegate(string targetUrl);" with one string parameter. What am I missing ?

Comment: ...ok, scrap that previous comment, I got it ! Once I removed the parameter and set method to void it works. Thx.

Comment: ...also find an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread