# new Thread() Parameterized start in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I've been doing this in Winforms forever :

```
new Thread((query_) =>
{
    Functions.UpdateInsert(query_);
}).Start(query);
```

But when I try to do this in WPF, the IDE tells me "Delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart' does not take 1 arguments."

Is this done differently in WPF?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not done differently in WPF, and there is ParametrizedThreadStart exists. Are you sure its not XNA?

Comment: Passing parameters to threads is obsolete. Just close over `query` in your lambda. Also, prefer a LongRunning task.

Answer (score 2):

try using it this way :

```
Thread t = new Thread(()=> Functions.UpdateInsert(query));
t.Start();
```

Comment: Since C# 3 introduced lambdas that can capture variables, there is little reason to use ParameterizedThreadStart anymore.

Comment: yes , still i foind it to be the safest/easiest way to do so ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread), you can see that Thread.Start can be called with no parameters.

I'm not sure if you're trying to do this all in one line, but if you start your thread like this instead, it should work just fine:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Functions.UpdateInsert(query_));
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Actually, [there is an overload with a parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Huh, I never knew that! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your `UpdateInsert` function does some database operation and you want to start a thread to not block the user interface while doing it you should try the Async/await approach to asynchronous programming:

```
public async void UpdateMyThing() {
     LoadingIndicator.IsEnabled = true; //or something like that
     var query = ...
     await Task.Run(() => Functions.UpdateInsert(query));
     LoadingIndicator.IsEnabled = false; //we are done
}
```

This leaves all the threading/waiting/complex stuff for the C# compiler and lets us keep it simple!

Otherwise, it seems there is nothing wrong with your syntax:

```
new Thread((a) => { }).Start(new object());
```

This works in my IDE.