# C# port is denied while thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, port

Using Microsoft Visual Expres, Win Form Application
In my application I am sending data from PC to microcontroller via serial communication. It works like that: App from PC send data - microcontroller do his program - in the end of microcontrollers program send character  to application - application receive character and send another data.

My problem is, when I wait for the character from microcontroller, whole App(in PC) becomes inactive(cant press any button or close the program).

Friend told me to try Threads. I tried to do it with thread(I am pretty new in threads). When I run my app it throw an exception: Acces to the port "COM6" is denied. It looks like that serial port is opened in one thread, before other thread close the port.

Is there any way to set the port as open for all threads?
Or any better ideas how to make my App active while waiting for response frommicrocontroller?

There are some lines of code with threads:

```
.
.
.
     poslat(data_all);   //sending data function               
     Thread t = new Thread(cakaj);
     t.Start(); // start of thread cakaj
.
.
.
```

there is function for sending data

```
static void poslat(string data)
{
    SerialPort COMport = new SerialPort();

    COMport.PortName = "COM6"; 
    COMport.BaudRate = 1200;
    COMport.DataBits = 8;
    COMport.Parity = Parity.None;
    COMport.StopBits = StopBits.One;

    COMport.Open();

    COMport.Write(data);
    COMport.WriteTimeout = 500;

    COMport.Close();

}
```

function for waiting for a character from microcotroller

```
void cakaj()
{
    SerialPort COMport = new SerialPort();
    int byteRead;

    COMport.PortName = "COM6"; // 
    COMport.BaudRate = 1200;
    COMport.DataBits = 8;
    COMport.Parity = Parity.None;
    COMport.StopBits = StopBits.One;

    COMport.Open(); //**Program points there with error message:Acces to the port "COM6" is denied.** 

    do
    { 
        byteRead = COMport.ReadByte();

    } while (byteRead != 75);   // ASCII K = 75
    t.Abort();

   COMport.Close();

    return;
}
```

Comment: Why not just have one thread that handles communication with the device over the serial port?

Comment: I dont know how to do it with 1 thread, when I run it in 1 thread, whole App becomes inactive(cant press any button or close the program)...

Comment: I'm suggesting having one thread just to handle communication with the device, not using one thread for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two different instances of `SerialPort COMport` using the same port `COM6`. What you can do is make the `COMport` variable as a field for your class and access that in `poslat` and `cakaj`.

Also, you can instead use the [DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead of making another thread.

Your code will look something like this.

```
class YourClass
{
    static SerialPort _COMport;
    int byteRead; //make byteRead a field so you can also share it outside cakaj
    SerialPort COMport //share COMport for poslat and cakaj
    {
        get
        {
            if(_COMport == null)
            {
               CreateCOMport();
            }
            return _COMport;
        }
    }

    void CreateCOMport()
    {
        _COMport = new SerialPort();
        _COMport.PortName = "COM6";
        _COMport.BaudRate = 1200;
        _COMport.DataBits = 8;
        _COMport.Parity = Parity.None;
        _COMport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _COMport.DataReceived += cakaj;
        //COMport will listen for any incoming data
        //when there is data available, method cakaj will run
    }

    void poslat(string data)
    {
        if (!COMport.IsOpen)
        {
            COMport.Open();
        }
        COMport.Write(data);
        COMport.WriteTimeout = 500;
    }
    void cakaj(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
            byteRead = COMport.ReadByte();

        } while (byteRead != 75);
        COMport.Close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: remember to call `COMport.Close()` somewhere within this class.
I changed the approach and there are many ways to improve it but I think it will do the work...

Comment: its not working,  still showing error  of denied COM6

Comment: are you opening `COM6` in any other methods? Or are there any other application outside your code opening `COM6`? That's the only possibilities I can think of that may deny access to a port.

Comment: see the EDIT on my answer.. try it

Comment: I little bit don´t understand what is input for function cakaj. And I need to run function cakaj at background. But its impossible when that function have input arguments: Cannot convert frommethod group to Threadstart

Comment: you mean this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread

Comment: you don't need to start `cakaj` in a new Thread. the statement `_COMport.DataReceived += cakaj;` will call `cakaj` when data is received from the port.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your Forms application's main thread to wait in a loop you have to make sure to give it the opportunity to handle events.

You can do that by modifying your waiting loop like this:

```
do
{ 
    Application.DoEvents(); // handle Windows Forms events

    byteRead = COMport.ReadByte();

} while (byteRead != 75);   // ASCII K = 75
```

This will make sure your app can still respond to events while waiting.

Of course this is only necessary when it is your application's main thread that's waiting. Background threads don't have to do this and in fact they **must not** do it.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents` is no replacement for proper programming. It will "work" for a while. Please at least add this as information.

Comment: tried to use application.DoEvents() but App is still inactive while running

Comment: Checking the docs I see that ReadByte() is a blocking call, meaning that execution will not return from ReadByte() until data is received from the serial port. That explains why DoEvents() has no effect. You will indeed have to do your communication in a background thread instead of the main thread.

Comment: Yes I know that, trying to do it with threads but there is problem with port, It is denied while getting into thread