# Access to Thread parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
internal static class RtfMerger
    {
        static object lockRtf = new object();
        static RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();

        static TaskCompletionSource<string> source = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        static Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
             //SOME code...
            // HOW TO THERE ACCESS TO THE PARAMETER input ?

        });

        public static Task<string> MergeRtf(params string[] input)
        {
            lock (lockRtf)
            {                               
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();  // <- HERE I CAN PASS input
                return source.Task;
            }
        }
```

Hello, how to modify declaration of thread, that it can receive parameter string[] input?

and there is full class with associated methods. hope it helps
because I've been worried about it for a long time and I don't know what to do
because I've been worried about it for a long time and I don't know what to do

```
{
    internal static class RtfMerger
    {
        static object lockRtf = new object();
        static RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();

        static TaskCompletionSource<string> source = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        static Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                //var richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox(); //TODO static na úrovni třídy [LOCK] //TODO async
                if (input != null && input.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (input[0].StartsWith(@"{\rtf"))
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Rtf = input[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Rtf = ConvertPlainTextToRTF(input[0], "Arial");
                    }
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                    for (int i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength;
                        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;

                        if (input[i].StartsWith(@"{\rtf"))
                        {
                            richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = input[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = ConvertPlainTextToRTF(input[i], "Arial");
                        }
                    }
                }
                source.SetResult(richTextBox1.Rtf);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                source.SetException(ex);
            }

        });

        public static Task<string> MergeRtf(params string[] input)
        {
            lock (lockRtf)
            {               
                //TODO přidat synchronizační objekt (může být 
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start(); //Přidat zámek k spuštění threadu
                return source.Task;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+how+to+pass+parameter+to+thread

Comment: Is there a way, how to do it without creating another method?

Comment: static Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        { //CODE });   in this type of enrollment

Comment: _"how to do it without creating another method?"_ -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3360586

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this:

```
internal static class RtfMerger
{
    static object lockRtf = new object();

    static TaskCompletionSource<string> source = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    public static Task<string> MergeRtf(params string[] input)
    {
        lock (lockRtf)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                //SOME code...

                // You can access `input` here.
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            return source.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant work with static RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox(); getting exception

Comment: yes, i need it declared as static in class

Comment: @SonDy - Sure, don't use it then. It wasn't needed in the code you provided and you didn't mention it in the question so I left it out.

Comment: @SonDy - And, even if you did use a `RichTextBox`, you can't access or update it in a thread other than the one used to create it.

Comment: @SonDy - You'd need to let us know what `//SOME code...` is trying to do.

Comment: if i declare it in class, it is count as different thread ?

Comment: @SonDy - Yes, the thread that creates the `RichTextBox` is different from the `Thread` you're creating. You can't access or update the `RichTextBox` from the created thread. Usually there's easy ways to get around that issue but we don't know what because you haven't told us what `SOME code...` is doing.

Comment: @SonDy - I saw your attempted edit. You can't do any of that in the created `Thread`. I rejected your edit. Please add the code to your question at the end (don't edit your existing code) as an edit.

Comment: "Some code" using richTextBox1.Rtf, richTextBox1.AppendText, richTextBox1.SelectionStart, richTextBox1.SelectionLength, richTextBox1.SelectedRtf and setting result as source.SetResult(richTextBox1.Rtf);

Comment: I'm trying to minimize memory leaks which RichTextBox doing, thats why it is that complicated

Comment: @SonDy - Using a thread does NOT fix memory leaks. Properly disposing of `IDisposable` objects is the primary way of eliminating memory leaks in managed code.

Comment: @SonDy - If you do have memory leaks caused by bugs in libraries that you don't control then the ONLY way to fix them is to run up a separate process, run your code there, and then kill the process.

Comment: how to run separate process in my example?

Comment: @SonDy - Look up `Process.Start`.

Comment: ok by running Process.Start() I will create new process, but how to kill them and how to run it again?

Comment: @SonDy - `var process = Process.Start("My.EXE"); process.Kill();`.