# How to call method in Form class from thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, winforms, timer

I'm trying to make a simple clock program with threads. In Form1 I want to create a new thread that's in ThreadProc(), take time, and sent back to Form1 send() method that will replace the text in label.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ThreadProc tP = new ThreadProc();
            Thread t = new Thread(tP.threadP);
            t.Start();
        }
        public void send(Object obj)
        {
            string time;
            try
            {
                time = (string)obj;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException)
            {
                time = " ";
            }
            if (label1.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { label1.Text = time; });
            else
                label1.Text = time;
        }


    }
```

```
internal class ThreadProc
    {
        public void threadP()
        {        
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            DateTime dateTime;
            do
            {
                dateTime = DateTime.Now;
                string time = dateTime.ToString(); 
                Thread t = new Thread(() => form1.send(time));
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            } while (true);
        }
    }
```

It ends up in infinite loop of Form1() -> threadP() -> Form1()... but without

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

I can't call send() in

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => form1.send(time));
```

The threadP() has to be in their own class and send() has to be in Form1 class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameters to ThreadStart method in Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread)

Comment: Not exacly. I know how to pass a parameters to method in threads. The problem is that threadP() can't see send() method that's in Form1 class so I have to use Form1 form1 = new Form1();. But if I use it the Form1() constructor is called again and the program stars from the start.

Comment: Pass a reference to the form to the thread and use it there

Comment: You *could* pass an [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate, but, since you want to *make a clock*, why don't you simply use a Timer? (making sure to check the actual time, since the timers' events, or `Thread.Sleep()` or `Task.Delay()` etc. will always *lose time*. A StopWatch can help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a reference to your form to the thread. You can then access it from there.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ThreadProc tP = new ThreadProc();
        Thread t = new Thread(tP.threadP);

        // Automatically end thread when application ends
        t.IsBackground = true;
        
        // Pass reference to this form to thread
        t.Start(this);
    }

    public void Send(string time)
    {
        if (Visible) // Check form wasn't closed
        {
            if (label1.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { label1.Text = time; });
            else
                label1.Text = time;
        }
    }
}

internal class ThreadProc
{
    public void threadP(object data)
    {
        // Get Form1 reference from start parameter
        Form1 form1 = data as Form1;
        
        DateTime dateTime;
        do
        {
            dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string time = dateTime.ToString();
            form1.Send(time);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Note that there are better designs to re-use the thread like passing an interface instead of the concrete Form1 class. But this is just a simple example.

When a Form and a background thread are so closely bound together, you usually use a `BackgroundWorker` instead of threads.

Comment: _"BackgroundWorker"_ - indeed. The best thing about `BackgroundWorker` is that it performs automatic _thread marshalling_ which is great for beginners.  No need for Invoke/BeginInvoke. :) +1